# Como retornar o ID de uma Categoria no WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Preciso retornar o ID dentro dessa função:

$field = odin_get_term_meta( ID DA CATEGORIA AQUI, 'cattitulo' );

Tentei com o get_term_meta() e o get_terms() e nada. Imagino que seja bem simples, não sei onde estou errando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar [get_term_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) com os dados que tiver da categoria.

```
Ex.:
// Retorna o objeto da categoria Animais Fofinhos
$categoria = get_term_by( 'slug', 'animais-fofinhos', 'cattitulo' );
```

O primeiro parâmetro aceita `slug`, `name`, `id` ou `term_taxonomy_id`.

```
e depois:
$field = odin_get_term_meta( $categoria->term_id, 'cattitulo' );
```

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo! Mas como chamar o 'animais-fofinhos' automaticamente ali no get_term_by ? (no meu caso seria dentro da página da categoria)

Comment: @GuilhermeSierra se você esta num arquivo de categoria, pode pegar o objeto na property `$wp_query->queried_object` ou diretamente o id na `$wp_query->queried_object_id`.

Comment: Perfeito! 100% Works. Obrigado

Comment: Legal @GuilhermeSierra. Se resolveu, marque a resposta como escolhida pras pessoas saberem.